# communicating between http handler and websocket handler in Cowboy

Tags: websocket, erlang, cowboy

I'd like to create a websocket app in Cowboy that gets its data from another Cowboy handler. Let's say that I want to combine the Echo_get example from cowboy: https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/tree/master/examples/echo_get/src

with websocket example

https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/tree/master/examples/websocket/src

in such a way that a GET request to Echo should send a "push" via websocket handler to the html page in that example.

What is the least complicated way to do it? Can I use "pipe" operator in some easy way ? Do I need to create and intermediate gen_something to pass messages between them? I would appreciate an answer with sample code that shows the glue code for the handlers - I do not really know where to start plumbing the two handlers together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A websocket handler in cowboy is a long lived request process to which you can send websocket or erlang messages.

In your case, there are 2 types of processes:

- websocket processes: websocket handlers with a websocket connection opened to clients.
- echo processes: processes when a client access the echo handler with a parameter.

The idea is that the echo process sends an erlang message to the websocket processes, that in turn will send a message to the client.

For your echo process can send a message to your websocket processes, you need to keep a list of websocket processes to which you want to send messages. [Gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) is a quite useful library for that purpose.

You can register processes to [gproc pubsub](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/blob/master/doc/gproc_ps.md) with `gproc_ps:subscribe/2`, and send messages to the registered processes with `gproc_ps:publish/3`.

Cowboy websocket processes receive erlang messages with the [websocket_info/3](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/HEAD/manual/cowboy_websocket/index.html#websocket_info) function.

So for example, the websocket handler could be like this:

```
websocket_init(_, Req, _Opts) ->
  ...
  % l is for local process registration
  % echo is the name of the event you register the process to
  gproc_ps:subscribe(l, echo),
  ...

websocket_info({gproc_ps_event, echo, Echo}, Req, State) ->
  % sending the Echo to the client
  {reply, {text, Echo}, Req, State};
```

And the echo handler like this:

```
echo(<<"GET">>, Echo, Req) ->
    % sending the echo message to the websockets handlers
    gproc_ps:publish(l, echo, Echo),
    cowboy_req:reply(200, [
        {<<"content-type">>, <<"text/plain; charset=utf-8">>}
    ], Echo, Req);
```

Comment: Just tested and it works! Thanks a lot! Do you know whether this method has any significant performance or scalability drawbacks (for example if pub and sub are on different machines, etc.), in comparison to other methods available in erlang? Would putting my own gen_server for oub/sub in between echo and websocket handlers be more efficient/scalable than gproc? I'm trying to understand whether I can stick to gproc for something more than a pet project (with significant communication on the pub/sub line (high pub/sub rates and numbers of nodes).