# Get a reference to Websocket connection in Cowboy

Tags: websocket, erlang, cowboy

I am following this example. I've modified my `ws_handler` slightly with "websocket_handle({text, <<"h">>}, State) ->
  {reply, {text, << "You h-in!">>}, State};"

to confirm I could detect specific messages.

I want to track websocket connections. In https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/1.0/guide/ws_handlers/ I see there's a Req object but I'm not sure what to search for to see what it contains.

I found this [communicating between http handler and websocket handler in Cowboy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712843/communicating-between-http-handler-and-websocket-handler-in-cowboy) ; I don't understand the meaning of the example answer though.

https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/tree/master/examples/websocket is using pkg_cowboy_commit = 1.0.4 in the `erlang.mk`, I haven't found an example using the latest 2.0 cowboy.

I want to track websocket connections via an ID or PID in a list, remove a reference when they disconnect, etc. I see no way of doing this besides sending the first bytes of a text on each message being the ID and this seems wrong.

In contrast socket.io, for example, you get `socket.id` - I want the same kind of reference in Erlang.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something like creating a process that references the websocket State. So on

`websocket_init(State) ->`

Pass the State to a process, and add that new process PID to the State of the websocket

then in

`websocket_handle({text, Msg}, State) ->`

a custom `{reply, Reply}` can be sent by loading data from the PID which is connected to custom domain logic.